# Construct an operator that fixes the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\overline{X}$ be its unique completion. We know that $\overline{X}$ can be partitioned into equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences via the relation $\sim$:
$$
\{x_n\} \sim \{y_n\}  \;\mbox{ iff }\; \lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-y_n\|=0.
$$
Can we construct a non trivial closed bounded operator  $T \in B(X)$ such that $T$ preserves an equivalence class, i.e $T \{x_n \}$ ~ $\{x_n \}$ for every $\{x_n\}$ belonging to the equivalence class $\overline{x}$ ?

Comment: A Banach space is already complete, so $\overline{X}$ is canonically isomorphic to $X$. If $T$ preserves equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, then $T = \operatorname{id}$, whether $X$ is complete or not.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Fischer ;) But I meant a $T$ which need not preserve all classes. Depending upon an element $x \in X$, we get an equivalence class $\overline{x}$ which has all sequences converging to it. Constructing such a $T$ which preserves, lets say, just  $\overline{x}$? Maybe since $\overline{X}$ is canonically isomorphic to $X$, we can get such an operator by trivial means.........

Comment: Ah, for a given $x$ you want an operator that fixes the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences converging to $x$ and don't care about other classes? Any operator with $Tx = x$ will do then (that again doesn't depend on $X$ being complete). That such operators exist for any normed space $X$ is an easy consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem(s).